# Canadian encryption key sizes

Tags: encryption, legal

I am looking after some legacy software that is compiled with VS2005 which uses .Net 2.0 Rijndael, which fails if the system locale is set to French Canadian. The plaintext is straight ASCII.

I have read that Canada's encryption key limits have been draconian in the past e.g. limited to 64 bit. Does anyone have information where I can get accurate current and historic information about crypto restrictions in Canada?

Comment: I'd guess that the cause is unrelated to crypto. Perhaps different numeric separators, the date format or different legacy charsets (`Encoding.Default`)

Comment: It turned out to be an encoding issue.  But the question was really about the state of crypto in Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to search for your first request. I am not aware of methods of finding software by its compiler.
As to your second question, these are the resources I've found:

[The legislative situation in Canada in 2006](http://www.lop.parl.gc.ca/content/lop/ResearchPublications/prb0565-e.html) - A summary of legislation that was in place back in 2006.

[Solicitor General’s Enforcement Standards](https://cippic.ca/uploads/Solicitor_General_Standards_Annotaed-2008.pdf) for Lawful Interception of
Telecommunications from 2008 - A standard describing what the Canadian authorities require from telecommunications solutions.

An [article](https://citizenlab.org/2015/08/canadas-quiet-history-of-weakening-communications-encryption/) from 2015 that discusses the state of encryption in Canada.

And in [this book](http://www.ruor.uottawa.ca/bitstream/10393/32424/1/9780776621838_WEB.pdf), chapter IX, page 266 - where he discusses the topic in depth.

Comment: Thanks, the first part was just for context.  I have source code.  I'll check out the rest of the docs soon.